# Property doesn`t exist on type object

Tags: angular

Code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from '../data.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-details',
  templateUrl: './details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./details.component.scss']
})
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {
user$: Object;
  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      params => this.user$ = params.id
    );
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  this.data.getUser(this.user$).subscribe(
  (data: Object) =>  this.user$ = data
);
  }

}
```

Problem is that it gives this error when I try to build: `ng build --prod`

```
 Property 'name' does not exist on type 'Object'
```

I also tried to replace `Object` with `any`. It didn`t worked out. I am a newbie in angular 6.

Comment: Did you mean `any`

Comment: The issue is that if you have define an object and using the keys such as "name" make sure you define it. Else if will throw error

Comment: Where you are using `name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are using `name` in the template with `user$` variable binding, as name$ is your bound with your asynchronous data.

So the best approach, in this case, will be -

```
user$: any;
```

and in template try to use **safe navigation operator (`?`)** like this -

```
{{name$?.name}}
```

Comment: Right thing. It is best approach

Comment: Thanks a lot brother for this.